# Is there a better way to input an $n$-cycle in GAP?

Tags: gap

In [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), we can generate permutations using, for example

```
alpha:=(1,2,3,4,5);
```

But, this method is not usable if we want to input the permutation $$(1,2,\ldots,n)$$ for some variable $n$.

It is possible to use

```
alpha:=PermList(List([1..n],i->(i mod n)+1));
```

for variable $n$, but this feels clumsy.

> **Question**: Is there a better way to input an $n$-cycle in GAP?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you, it's a good question. In brief, your suggestion to use `PermList` is right, but its argument may be assembled faster:

```
alpha:=PermList(Concatenation([2..n],[1]));
```

Now a bit longer version of the reply with timings. First, another alternative is `MappingPermListList`:

```
gap> n:=5;;MappingPermListList([1..n],Concatenation([2..n],[1]));
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Nevertheless, your suggestion with `PermList` is already slightly faster:

```
gap> n:=100000;;for i in [1..100] do alpha:=PermList(List([1..n],i->(i mod n)+1));od;time;
984
gap> n:=100000;;for i in [1..100] do alpha:=MappingPermListList([1..n],Concatenation([2..n],[1]));od;time;
1361
```

However, one could do even better, avoiding writing `mod n)+1` and using `Concatenation` instead. Then the performance is ~20 times faster:

```
gap> n:=100000;;for i in [1..100] do alpha:=PermList(Concatenation([2..n],[1]));od;time;
47
```

Summarising, I'd recommend to use `PermList` in this particular case when one needs to create a cycle $(1,2,...n)$. In a general case, one should choose between `PermList` and `MappingPermListList` dependently on the data available.

P.S. Note that the naive approach to multiply transpositions does not scale well at all:

```
gap> n:=5;; alpha:=(1,2);;for j in [3..n] do alpha:=alpha*(1,j);od; alpha;
(1,2,3,4,5)
gap> n:=100000;; alpha:=(1,2);;for j in [3..n] do alpha:=alpha*(1,j);od; time;
14429
```

Comment: P.S. Any suggestions for the syntax to specify _n_-cycles?

Comment: @ Alexander could you please explain what is the meaning of i->(i mod n)+1?

Comment: @smaz: `->` is a GAP shortcut for one-argument function. ` i->(i mod n)+1?` creates a function `f(i)` such that `i` from `[1..n-1]` is mapped to `i+1`, and `n` is mapped to `1`. On other inputs it will act appropriately (but in the example above it is called for `i` from `[1..n]`). P.S. there should be no space between @ and username to ping, I've just occasionally discovered your question.