# List vs Permutation representation.

Tags: permutations, gap

If we have a list

xx:=[3,7,17,16,15]; and I want to convert this list into permutation like

xx:=(3,7,17,16,15); I used PermList(xx) for this but it doesn't convert it in the required form. How can I see this in GAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a list into a cycle, you could use [`MappingPermListList`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap21.html#X7B5A19098406347A), but you'll need to construct the list of images yourself (easy to do by hand, but even easier is just typing in the permutation, so I'll assume you need to do this in a program).

```
gap> cycleAsList := [3,7,17,16,15];;
gap> genericCycle := PermList( Concatenation( [2..Size(cycleAsList)],[1] ) );
(1,2,3,4,5)
gap> cycle := MappingPermListList( Permuted( cycleAsList, genericCycle ), cycleAsList );
(3,7,17,16,15)
```

Comment: Please see also this question: [Is there a better way to input an n-cycle in GAP?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/484290/)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that xx does not define a valid permutation. To be a valid permutation, it must contain each of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,\text{Length(list)}$ exactly once.

Please see the [documentation for PermList](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap42.html#X78D611D17EA6E3BC).

Comment: Thanks, only the link was pointing to GAP3 manual from 1990s, a copy of which is available from Jean Michel's homepage. I've corrected the link.

Comment: (Google includes GAP3 manual in search results so often that now on the GAP website it was made available only as an archive)